# uninitialized constant Psych::Syck with Rails 3/Rubygems 1.6.2/bundler 1.0.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, ruby-1.9.2

I'm trying to setup my ruby on rails dev environment on my macbook pro but running into this error:

> /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:289:in `load': uninitialized constant
>   Psych::Syck (NameError)    from
>   /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:289:in`_load'

I tried using another yaml engine by specifying syck in config/boot.rb but that didn't work.

> require 'yaml' 
>   YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'

I'm using 
Rails 3/Ruby 1.9.2-p180/Bundler 1.0.10/RubyGems 1.6.2. I installed ruby 1.9.2 via brew.

Answer (score 4):

Update rubygems worked for me.

```
gem update --system
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have this :

```
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.0.0.beta.20"
```

remove ', ">= 2.0.0.beta.20"'

```
gem "rspec-rails"
```

It works for me

Comment: Same for me. Removing the gem version for mongoid fixed it.

Comment: I am very new to ruby. From where i can change this settings?

Comment: In your `rails_app_name/Gemfile`.

Answer (score 0):

[GemCutter rake build now throws "undefined method 'write' for #<Syck::Emitter:...." after updating to rubygems 1.5.0 on ruby 1.9.2 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932881/gemcutter-rake-build-now-throws-undefined-method-write-for-syckemitter) maybe related?